# Is the "stupid" in "Keep it simple, stupid" a form of address or a second adjective that you should "keep it"?

Tags: adjectives, vocatives

i.e. is the comma to signify the boundary between the instruction and the recipient of it (that is to say, "Hey, stupid! Keep it simple"), or is it serving the function of an "and" (as is sometimes used in US English but rare in British).

Comment: Can you explain why you think that the second reading (comma means *and*) is a viable candidate for a reasonable interpretation of this saying (so that an argument is needed to rule it out)? To me, and I suppose a fair number of other people, this reading appears to be a non-starter (what would it be to keep something stupid and why would it be a good thing?). It would probably make the page more useful to those who come to it in the future, if you could elaborate on the matter.

Comment: @jsw29 Not so silly a doubt if it comes from a non-native English speaker (maybe this question should have been asked on English Learner SE). In some languages that comma can be interpreted as an "and".

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine comma can be interpreted as "and" in English too and I think the question is a great one.

Comment: @Prof.Falken Yep, but compared with other languages (e.g. Italian, which is my native language) it seems to me that this use is less common (It's just a feeling based on my experience, I may be wrong, though) .

Comment: @jsw29 I had refrained from providing my own opinion on the subject to avoid bias, but now that there are a few answers already... I always believed the first reading to be the case, but recently I saw someone represent KISS as "Keep it simple and stupid". It seemed a ridiculous interpretation but I thought best to Google before correcting them, and found a few more examples of people using that interpretation (mainly in the software development sector). There didn't seem to be any definitive proof one way or the other.

Comment: @ChrisA I think it has taken on a "domesticated" extra meaning of "Keep it Simple and Stupid", especially in software dev.

Comment: @Prof.Falken Yes, I second your opinion. Moreover in the last decade or two I saw a steep increase in trying to be politically correct at all costs, even wrt. well-established terminology. to the point where the technical meaning of "master vs. slave" systems in computer engineering and electronics has been challenged as "non inclusive". Meh!. So I may imagine someone to bend the meaning of that KISS interpretation to avoid calling someone "stupid" (even when referred to oneself!). Self irony is a dying beast nowadays, sigh!

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine I don't think it even takes a conscious effort, if you are new to an expression, the less edgy interpretation may be the default. I purposefully refrained from making a judgement, but I think the "politically correct" movement isn't just a bland thing for its own sake. I think it's also a function of more and more communication being in text, where nuance and wit is hard.

Comment: Of interest, perhaps: the version I first encountered (early 2000s, probably) was "Keep it stupid simple," where "stupid" is acting adverbially, modifying "simple": "Keep it stupidly [i.e. ridiculously] simple." Probably another "domesticated" version.

Comment: *Stupid*, like *deadass*, is totes (that’s *totally*) a flat adverb in California.

Comment: @jsw29 I admittedly always thought it was something like the first interpretation (without knowing it has a comma). And stupid could be the opposite of unnecessarily complex or "too smart" for your own good. Anyways, I'm now enlightened.

Comment: Isn't it the point that it's ambiguous? That it can be read both ways? [Helpful if you meant  vocative, and the offense is taken, then you can backtrack with "no, no, I meant 'simple and stupid'; check out this SE thread about the subject".]

Comment: The use of a comma as a replacement for "and" is called "asyndeton".

Comment: Related: [What does “It’s the loyalty (or the economy), stupid,” mean?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/190234).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

One thing to note is that the [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) on the subject is a bit specious:

> First seen partly in American English by at least 1938 . . . the
> variant “Keep it Short and Simple” is attested from a 1938 issue of
> the *Minneapolis Star*.

*Partly*? Very partly; there is no sign of an acronym at play — no discernible throughline to KISS, no sign of “variation.”

A quick search of Google Books does indeed turn up *keep it simple, stupid* under the item [*Constitutionality of the General Accounting Office*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Constitutionality_of_the_General_Account/Ecdfrvrb5P0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22keep+it+simple+stupid%22&pg=RA1-PA129&printsec=frontcover) (1938), but one need only  scroll into the document about 20 pages to see that it actually appears in a [1996 hearing of the Committee on Government Reform and Oversight](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Constitutionality_of_the_General_Account/Ecdfrvrb5P0C?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Constitutionality+of+the+General+Accounting+Office%22+%22Committee+on+Government+Reform+and+Oversight%22&pg=RA1-PP7&printsec=frontcover).

I can find the phrase in print as early as 1961, in a [*Popular Mechanics*  column titled “Sidelights from the Pentagon”](https://books.google.com/books?id=e98DAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA12&dq=%22keep+it+simple+stupid%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwierOubwYf_AhWzIX0KHWN5CT4Q6AF6BAgDEAI#v=onepage&q=%22keep%20it%20simple%20stupid%22&f=false):

> PROJECT KISS is a current Navy program which stands for, not the old
> social pastime, but for a new slogan, “Keep It Simple, Stupid!” It’s
> a reminder that simple design of weapons systems increases reliability
> and cuts costs.

By the early 60s, it seems the term was “old” — [in common usage](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22keep+it+simple+stupid%22&tbs=cdr:1,cd_max:1969&tbm=bks&ei=PdJqZPKrLILr9APstKuQCA&start=10&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwiyvpm074f_AhWCNX0KHWzaCoIQ8tMDegQIEBAE&biw=2184&bih=1150&dpr=2). This is from [*Five Years to Freedom —
The True Story of a Vietnam POW*](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Five_Years_to_Freedom/sM6VVTcn6wUC?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22Five+Years+to+Freedom%22+%22keep+it+simple+stupid%22&pg=PT159&printsec=frontcover) (originally published in 1971), wherein the author recounts a 1964 experience of his:

> The old “KISS” formula, “Keep it simple, stupid,” served as my guide
> as I built the biography which would allow me to deny knowledge of the
> areas they have displayed an interest in.

---

With or without a comma, none of this particularly proves whether *stupid* was meant as a form of direct address or not (I doubt that generals and engineers think much about the subtleties of punctuation).

But if simple is good here, then simple is smart — not stupid. That would leave — you (the addressee) as the primary candidate . . .

Comment: As an American English speaker, I never thought of "stupid" as a second adjective. Nobody ever says "Keep it simple, stupid!" because you did something smart. It is usually used to admonish someone for over-complicating something. It's also a bit sarcastic. I hear "simple" and "stupid" being used similarly, implying "simple" is "stupid", but this particular usage is also a play on words. Keeping it simple is smart, and the person being addressed is therefore stupid for making something overly complex.

Comment: The quotation from *Popular Mechanics* does not say that the slogan KISS is "old". It implies *kissing* is an old social pastime. The slogan is specifically characterized as new. I'm not sure I believe James Rowe when he says it's an old formula.

Comment: @verbose — I am quoting Rowe — not *Popular Mechanics* — on “old.” You can believe him or not. Aside: His KISS is the earliest example at [Green’s Dictionary of Slang](https://greensdictofslang.com/entry/vjr3bsq).

Comment: I know you were quoting Rowe, I was merely pointing out that ten years before Rowe, *Popular Mechanics* was citing it as new rather than old. The fact that Green's Dictionary has Rowe as its earliest example doesn't exactly bolster the case that the phrase was "old" by the time Rowe mentions it, does it? Perhaps it's "old" for Rowe in the sense that slang does age pretty quickly; nobody says "derp" any more, and it was all the rage a decade ago

Answer (score 25):

> is the comma to signify the boundary between the <s>instruction</s> interjection, 'hey', and the recipient of it ("Hey, stupid! Keep it simple")

Yes.

> or is it serving the function of an "and"

No. That would make no sense.

Comment: Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146220/discussion-on-answer-by-greybeard-is-the-stupid-in-keep-it-simple-stupid-a); please do not continue the discussion here.

Comment: This is how it was used in the programming department I worked in in the 1970's and was a verbal reminder of a programmer's ethos that writing complicated code when a simpler approach was available should be avoided. It was generally used in a light-hearted manner and not taken as in insult. The only political correction I ever heard was "Keep it simple Simon" to avoid the directly saying the recipient of the observation was stupid. Aurally I don't recall any of the tech people saying the phrase as if there were a comma in it.

Comment: While using a comma in place of "and", acronyms are known for having odd phrasing - another situation with odd phrasing is headlines, which are often abbreviated and end up sounding similar: "New Government Policy Simple, Stupid" sounds alright to my ears.

Answer (score 9):

It's rare to use a comma between a pair of predicative adjectives unless one is in apposition (a synonym to elucidate [a] or a near-synonym to [1] develop, [2] amend (make a minor correction or add precision) or [3] bracket (where an 'and' is considered too divisive and a slash too informal) the required sense [b]):

- [a]  *[T]he revelations have been uniformly anticlimactic. The exchanges, most reports agree, are quotidian, mundane.* [[Rebecca Traister; The Cut; 2015](https://www.thecut.com/2015/09/what-hillary-clintons-emails-really-reveal.html)]
- [b1]  *[The dog was] found to be very thin, emaciated ....* [RSPCA Cymru; Facebook; 2018](https://www.facebook.com/rspcacymru/photos/a.277888115603557/1735541186504902/?type=3)]
- [b2]  *[W]hile the reserves are large, enormous, at the present time, the battalions have been far under strength.* [[Hansard; Army Estimates; Vol 160; 1906-7](https://hansard.parliament.uk/commons/1906-07-12/debates/b075bd9a-ec14-4205-a26a-f47a01e5d97e/ArmyEstimates1906%E2%80%937)]
- [b3] *She claimed that Lord Haw Haw's words were misleading, disingenuous.*
- [b3] *The results of the experiment were disappointing, frustrating.*

Since this is not the case with 'keep it simple, stupid', it is highly likely that 'stupid' here is a vocative, as in 'keep it simple, Stan'.

Comment: I would say that *stupid* could be understood as a near synonym to *simple* (*OED*: stupid, foolish, feeble-minded) that adds precision (*stupid* is a stupider *simple*). It may not seem likely, but we really don’t know.

Comment: 'Keep it fairly stupid ...' seems extremely unlikely in any meaningful adjuration.

Answer (score 5):

Like many idioms, different interpretations are often just as valid as one another.

"Hey Stupid, Keep it simple!" is pretty self explanatory. "Don't be stupid, do things simply"

"Keep it simple (and) Stupid" works as an admonishment to keep your work straightforward and choose the "dumb" approach rather than being too clever about it.

Anecdotally, I work in the software industry, and there are always many many different ways to accomplish any given task.
In general, the accepted attitude in my place of work is that it's better to write a big sprawling piece of code using simple techniques than a clever and efficient solution.

Clever code is dense code, and dense code is often difficult to immediately understand for other developers.
Chunky and Dumb code is comparatively easy to pick up and modify without wasting serious time analysing what your clever colleague did.
Given that time is money and there is no prize for writing beautiful code, it's almost always better to reserve your cleverness for things that really merit it.

"Keep it simple and stupid" is a mantra in my team.

Comment: Stupidity, in the literal sense, is a characteristic of human beings. What exactly does it mean to characterise something other than a human being as stupid (or dumb)? Moreover stupidity is normally regarded as something undesirable, so it is puzzling why keeping something stupid would be recommended. All this needs to be explained before reading the comma as *and* can be regarded as even a viable candidate for a reasonable interpretation of this saying.

Comment: @jsw29 "What exactly does it mean to characterise something other than a human being as stupid (or dumb)?", well I don't agree "stupid errors" are a thing (and can be done by not-stupid people too). In addition, "stupid code" is something that is not a negative thing in a software development context (see [this](http://graphics.cs.cmu.edu/courses/15-466-f17/notes/stupid-code.html), for example). It may be considered "programmer jargon". Programmers are encouraged to write "stupid code" because it means it will be more reliable.

Comment: Everyone is stupid sometimes. KISS is acknowledging that the poor sap who has to understand your code in a year's time _might be you_.

Comment: @Miral Even a few weeks later can be enough to have to re-analyze your own code just to be able to understand what you previously did. Even if the code was well-documented. And you usually realize at that point you over-complicated things.

Comment: @Miral A related observation is that if you write the "cleverest" code you can, you won't be clever enough to debug it.

Comment: @user888379 Yep! Especially when you write the code under one-in-a-lifetime enlightened condition or under [mild effect of booze](https://observer.com/2012/04/bottoms-up-the-ballmer-peak-is-real-study-says/) ([obligatory XKCD reference](https://xkcd.com/323/)).

Comment: @jsw29 I take you're not a programmer? When developing software, it is absolutely desirable to keep components stupid, i.e. keep them with as little "business logic" as possible. See for example [Dumb Components and Smart Components](https://medium.com/@thejasonfile/dumb-components-and-smart-components-e7b33a698d43). Because of that, I always understood "KISS" as meaning "simple **and** stupid"

Comment: @QBrute, that is indeed a possible explanation, but **(1)** it is far from obvious, so it should be a part of the answer (if that is indeed what the answerer had in mind), and **(2)** it works only when the phrase is used within the world of programming and related technology, while it often appears in other contexts.

Comment: @LorenzoDonatisupportUkraine, my question what it means to say that something other than a human being is stupid was not a rhetorical question: sometimes, as in *stupid errors*, that makes sense. One can see how the meaning of *stupid* in *stupid errors* is derived from its primary meaning. The question is what it means in this case, and the example of *stupid errors* does not help with that, as stupid errors are something bad, not something to be encouraged.

Comment: From the DSP realm:  Some efficient algorithms are much larger pieces of code than an inefficient.  Consider the DFT (Digital Fourier Transform) and the FFT (Fast Fourier Transform, also digitalized).  The FFT has a lot of code, and it is also hard to understand.  The DFT is very easy to understand (just a loop with some trig functions with coefficients).  Thus, to do it efficiently requires much more code, at least in this case.

Comment: For a meat-space example, simple and brute-force approaches are often more robust than clever and complex solutions. In biology, typically a strong joint is a simple one, and you lose flexibility as you gain strength. In product-design, simpler often translates to more effective simply because the user doesn't need to spend any time figuring out how to use it.

Comment: @Ruadhan2300, your last comment explains why somebody would recommend that something be kept simple, but that is not at issue here. This page is about the meaning and role of the **word** *stupid* in this recommendation, not about the overall meaning of the recommendation, which is obvious.

Comment: @jsw29 The gist is that avoiding being too clever in your solutions to problems has its advantages, usually in robustness and readability. Keep it stupid, because stupid is often better. complexity goes hand-in-hand with fragility and incomprehensibility.

Answer (score 4):

As a native english speaker, it clearly reads to me "keep it simple [you] stupid [person]". The tone is lighthearted although slightly brash.

To avoid the brashness, there are alternate variations (which are most certainly backronyms):

- "keep it simple, silly"
- "keep it stupid simple" (which means "keep it utterly simple")

But to underscore: the usage of the term "stupid" squarely describes a proverbial person.

Some suggest that the phrase has a softer meaning, but this is not at all true. Nobody would phrase a statement like "keep it simple utterly" unless rambling when speaking. And consider that the word "stupid" here is a shortened form of the word "stupidly", having its `-ly` suffix omitted. In every case where "stupid" is used as an adjective without its suffix (e.g. "stupid simple", "stupid easy", "stupid smart") it always precedes its object. It never comes after. So the plain interpretation (and *only* interpretation) is "keep it simple, [you] stupid [person]".

Comment: It should be noted that this answer introduces (and then rightly rejects) a third possibility, in addition to the two offered by the OP.

Answer (score 4):

Having been a techie for the last 50 years, on and off, here is what I know.
It is really easy when on the hunt for the "perfect solution" to go down a rabbit hole of modifications to the initial design, with a result that is less than robust (think Rube Goldberg).

"Keep it simple, Stupid" is a rejoinder the designers/engineers gave to THEMSELVES to keep focused on the solving the problem and not keep trying to fix the solution.

Calling *yourself* Stupid should not offend anyone.

Comment: How exactly does this address the question? The question is not about the overall meaning of the recommendation to keep things simple, which is obvious.

Comment: @jsw29 the question is about the meaning of the word "stupid".  This answer is trying to address the harshness of the most obvious interpretation.  I think it's misguided, because I've seen it used more often to refer to somebody else's work rather than your own when it looks like they're over-complicating things.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve always understood it as a vocative (Keep it simple, [O] stupid [person].)  There are other similar sayings, like James Carville saying about the 1992 U.S. presidential election, “It’s the economy, stupid.”

I’d say the other way, “Keep it Simple and Stupid,” or “Keep it stupidly simple.”  I don’t think a list without a conjunction would be grammatical here.

I’ve also frequently heard, “Keep it simple, shithead.”  (No, not addressed at me.)

Answer (score -1):

It is both.

The ambiguity helps bring the message across, as the message serves as an example of how using ambiguous but technically correct grammar makes it difficult to interpret a basic four word sentence.

Comment: Lacking a citation, I would disagree with this interpretation. It clearly reads to me as addressing someone as "stupid" telling them to "keep it simple". Not "keep it simple (and) stupid" at all.

Comment: Per [Edwin Ashworth's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/607924/3347), this isn't actually a case where it can be correct grammar.  Even if it were, ambiguity isn't conducive to understanding -- and trying to make an extremely short and simple sentence somehow unintelligible absolutely _detracts_ from the actual point.